# Sharepoint Online iframed system with login

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

What's the best way to do a unified login between a Sharepoint Online page and an iFramed in system that also needs it's own login. Is there any way for me to let the iframe know that the user is logged in and give the iframe the user email ?
Similar to what FB does with page tabs and apps.

Comment: Did find this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163091%28v=office.15%29.aspx but unfortunately only available next year.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do:

First thing, do not give source to IFRAME element by default. Do it on main page's onload().

1. Add a custom JS in IFRAME page called IFRAME_READEMAIL() - will be called on IFRAME's page load. Add code where you read a HIDDEN VARIABLE - hfEmail
2. In your main page, using JQUERY, on load GET THE IFRAME object & set the hfEmail's value

The flow is like this:
The Main page gets loaded, then sets the IFRAME's SRC to required page, then sets the hidden field of IFRAME. The IFRAME picks up the HIDDEN variable & uses it.

Not sure what URL you get in IFRAME's location.href, but If you get the actual IFRAME's SRC as location.href, then you can set the SRC in main page like :
`$('MYFAME').attr('src','http://mysite/mypage.aspx?email=' + YOURVARIABLE)`